# iText Volumen License print count

Tags: pdf, itext

I know iText Volume license is based on how many PDF is getting printed. I cannot find any documentation how to setup a counter. We have JAR files declared in POM and we are building war file. What else needs to be done?

How is this number of PDFs are calculated? Who calculates them, iText or Customer?

See below, Answer to this question involves programming.

Comment: That is a question that you can really ask on the iText JIRA, because you are a customer. You paid for your support contract, now put it to good use! :) Due to an upgrade, JIRA will be offline tomorrow between 09:30 and 11:30 CEST, but you will still be able to send email. If you personally aren't one of the 3 registered support users for your company, ask the person responsible for the purchase, or contact our sales to change the registered users if you replace someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is also answered on the [official web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/): [How can I log the number of documents / bytes I've processed?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-log-number-documents-bytes-ive-processed)

Customers with a capacity rental license are asked to count the metric that was agreed using the `Counter` mechanism. We have a very simple `SysoCounter` class that writes information to the `System.out`.

You can test this `SysoCounter` like this:

```
CounterFactory.getInstance().setCounter(new SysoCounter());
```

Obviously, it's not very useful to have all that information in the `System.out`. Depending on how you want to store the document count (e.g. you might want to update a value in a database), you should write your own `Counter` implementation and use `CounterFactory.getInstance().setCounter(yourCounter)` to get the mechanism in place.

Comment: Can we use Google Analytic to count pages?  I think there is a way of putting a tag, etc.

Comment: I don't know if Google Analytics counts PDFs. I don't think so: Google Analytics requires JavaScript in a page.

Comment: I am creating PDF using XMLWorkerHelper and a xhtml template.  I guess the only way of knowing, is to do a POC.